# Which tense should be used here?

Tags: tenses

Suppose I need to talk about some specific action that was continuously happening in the past (and it has completed at some time, for example about my parents college studying period) but I even was not born at that time (i.e. I've never seen(or participated in) that action).

For example, I want to tell someone something like below:
When my father was going to college(every day), he was reading a newspaper on his way to the college (every day).
Seems my sentence is not constructed correctly. Maybe I need to use Past Perfect Continuous tense?

What tense should I use in such cases?

Comment: I'll post as an answer and delete the comments, tidy things up a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use the past habit for this:

> When my father was at (more natural than going to) college, he would read a newspaper on the way there (every day).

Or if you want to make it a bit cleaner:

> My father would read a newspaper every day on his way to college.